# why is $f\equiv 0?$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $f:[0,\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and $f(0)=0$. 
Then prove that $f$ is identically zero if $$\int_0^{\pi}f(x)\cos(nx)dx= 0$$ for all $n\in\{0\}\cup \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Is this really true? Since i think $\int_0^\pi xcos(nx)dx=0$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\bar f\colon[-\pi,\pi]\to\mathbb{R}$ be the even extension of $f$ to $[-\pi,\pi]$, that is, $\bar f(x)=f(-x)$ if $-\pi\le x<0$. Then $\bar f$ is continuous. Since it is even,
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi \bar f(x)\sin(n\,x)\,dx=0.
$$
It follows that all he Fourier coefficients of $\bar f$ are equal to $0$. This implies that $\bar f$ is identically zero. Can you see why?

Comment: You should ask that question as a comment, not by changing the original question. By Plancherels theorem $\int|f(x)|^2dx=0$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f\equiv0$.

Comment: Can you mention other problems that resort to the same trick?